# How let Derby Network Server show detailed log?

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I use the Derby in client/server way and I start the server, and there is a derby.log shows in my directory. But I want to know the details about the server's process, there is any way to let the Derby to show the detail log？ In the derby.log, there just have a litter information about the Derby start and shut down.

The Derby is implemented entirely in Java, so I think there must have print the log like 
log.info|log.debug|log.error, if there is some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derby was started before the java.util.Logging api was added, so Derby does not use that. But the [manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/crefproper22250.html) describes a some properties that control what is logged to Derby log. In particular derby.language.logStatementText and derby.language.logQueryPlan